# A "wrong" counterexample to splitting lemma in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a "wrong" counterexample to the following statement in linear algebra but I don't see why it's wrong: let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map between vector spaces. Then, $V$ is the direct sum of $\textrm{im}(T)$ and $\ker(T)$.

Let $V$ be the space of polynomials over a field with degree less than or equal to n, and let $T \colon V \to V$ be the differential operator. Then $\textrm{im}(T)$ is the space of polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n-1$, and $\ker(T)$ is the base field. Their direct sum is a proper subspace of $V$.

Comment: Their sum isn't direct. For example, $\;1=Tx\;,\;\;T(1)=0\implies 1\in\ker T\cap\text{Im}\,T\;$ ...but this is a counterexample to the fact that that sum is direct!

Comment: There is a typo: $T$ should be a map $V \to V$

Comment: It is not true that $V$ is that direct sum; in fact $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is not even a subspace of $V$.

Comment: I feel even more confused after reading all the comments and answers...

Comment: @Vladimir That may mean you need to go over the basics again.

Comment: @Vladimir we are having trouble reading your question. Do you believe the statement, or the counterexample? Why?

Comment: @hunter I now understand I gave a wrong counterexample to a wrong statement... Now I just wonder if someone could give me a good reference on this (a nice treatment of this in a linear algebra book).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement of the theorem should be the following: let $T \colon V \to V$ be a linear transformation such that $\textrm{ker}(T) \cap \textrm{im}(T) = 0$, then
$$
V = \textrm{ker}(T) \oplus \textrm{im}(T).
$$
As mentioned in the comments above, this theorem does not directly apply to the given linear transformation $T \colon V \to V$, because the subspaces $\textrm{ker}(T)$ and $\textrm{im}(T)$ intersect nontrivially (their intersection is the constants).

However, it is true that $V$ is isomorphic to $U \oplus W$ as vector spaces, where $U \simeq \textrm{ker}(T)$ and $W = \textrm{im}(T)$. The isomorphism is not equality, in the sense that $V$ is not the direct sum of the subspaces $\textrm{ker}(T) \subset V$ and $\textrm{im}(T)$.

Comment: In the example given by the OP the sum is *not* direct at all to begin with. Read the comments below the question.

Comment: This is true, just to add something to this. It seems like OP may be confusing inner direct products with external direct products. Which is understandable as the notation is the same.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong as it appears now, but can easily be turned into correct saying that what is true is that $\;V\cong U\oplus W\;$ , with $\;U\cong\ker T\;,\;\;W\cong\text{Im}\,T\;$ . This follows at once from the dimensions theorem, and in fact one can choose $\;U=\ker T\;$ .

Comment: Is this not the same as saying $V \simeq \textrm{ker}(T) \oplus \textrm{im}(T)$? You're just giving a (possibly) different isomorphism on each factor.

Comment: @msteve It certainly can depend on  agreed meanings, yet in this case it may say that the sum of $\;\ker T\;,\;\;\text{Im}\;T\;$ is *always* direct, which is far from being true.

Comment: Good point @Timbuc, I've edited the post to try to avoid any such ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

I think everyone else is reading your question backwards. You believe that a statement about direct sums is true, but you've written down what you know to be a counterexample to it. You want to know what is wrong with your counterexample.

However, the counterexample is correct, because the statement is wrong. First, as was pointed out in the comments, the statement $V$ is the direct sum of $\text{im}(T)$ and $\ker(T)$ doesn't even make sense unless $V = W$.

But even for this, as your counterexample shows, the statement is not true.

What is true is the following: $V$ is the direct sum of $\ker(T)$ and a subspace $V'$ which is mapped isomorphically to $\text{Im}(T)$ via $T$, i.e. $T|_V'$ is an isomorphism to $\text{Im}(T)$.